# Magento display sub's sub category in layered navigation

Tags: magento, attributes, layered-navigation

I have Category hierarchy as,

```
Root Category 
Category 1
    Category 1.1
        Category 1.1.1
        Category 1.1.2
        Category 1.1.3
    Category 1.2
        Category 1.2.1
        Category 1.2.2
        Category 1.2.3
    Category 1.3
Category 2
.       .       .
.       .       .
.       .       .
```

**Question**
After Clicking first category (eg. Catergory 1). In left side layered Navigation, it dispays only it's sub category. Not sub's sub category.

Eg. I want this after Clicking Category 1 in layered navigation as,

```
Category 1.1
    Category 1.1.1
    Category 1.1.2
    Category 1.1.3

Category 1.2
    Category 1.2.1
    Category 1.2.2
    Category 1.2.3

Category 1.3
    Category 1.3.1
    Category 1.3.2
    Category 1.3.3
```

And after clicking Category 2,

```
Category 2.1
    Category 2.1.1
    Category 2.1.2
    Category 2.1.3

Category 2.2
    Category 2.2.1
    Category 2.2.2
    Category 2.2.3

Category 2.3
    Category 2.3.1
    Category 2.3.2
    Category 2.3.3
```

and so on ....

How can i achieve this .. please help .. Thank you..

Comment: can you provide code inside `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml`

Comment: here is my code inside view.phtml http://pastebin.com/j9PRjUxh